# Is HCE Host-based Card Emulation for contactless card only?

Tags: android, hce

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099849/host-based-card-emulation-any-guidance-please), based Card Emulation for contactless card only? What if I want to use HCE with a visa card that does not have visaWave functionality?

1) Can I use back the visaWave AID?

2) What's the data format to send back to the terminal? Can it be implemented?

Comment: Sorry to bother you, can you please explain the reason for downvoting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HCE emulates a Contactless Smart Card over your NFC chip (aka you are enabling the phone to be a smart card).  You can implement an NFC reader that reads a contactless smart card in a different way, but that's not related to Host Card Emulation (HCE).

Comment: So means HCE can't support cards without contactless functionality?

Comment: That is correct.  Only contactless.  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce.html#SupportedProtocols