# NDEF Message with HCE Android

Tags: android, nfc, ndef, hce

I wanna emulate a host card with the HCE feature from Android. For that I extend the service class HostApduService and overwrite following method:

```
 public byte[] processCommandApdu(byte[] commandApdu, Bundle extras) {
    if (Arrays.equals(SELECT_APDU, commandApdu)) {
        NdefMessage message = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord  [] {NdefRecord.createTextRecord("en", "test"});
       return message.toByteArray();
    } else {
        return UNKNOWN_CMD_SW;
    }
}
```

With a second device its possible to receive data from the HCE Service.  The problem is that I always receive "Type A" Tag, but I need a NDEF Message.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate: please have a look at this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24143832/android-4-4-2-pn532-nfc-reader-and-nfc-card-emulation#24157624

Answer (score 10):

For anyone who stuck on this issue, I have read [NFCForum-TS-Type-4-Tag](http://apps4android.org/nfc-specifications/NFCForum-TS-Type-4-Tag_2.0.pdf) which proposed by @Michael Roland. The whole idea is correct. All you need is to simulate the process SEND and RECEIVED commands to convert the byte array to a [NDEF](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/Ndef) message. I created two repositories, one conclude the whole package about converting string to a [NDEF message](https://github.com/underwindfall/NFCAndroid) and the other one is a [iOS Reader NDEF TAG](https://github.com/underwindfall/NFCReaderiOS) to verify whether Android HCE is correct or not.

So Good luck!

Answer (score 7):

Emulating a tag that is detected as NDEF tag using Android HCE is not as simple as sending an NDEF message in response to a SELECT APDU. You would need to implement the NFC Forum Type 4 Tag Operation specification. You can get that specification from the [NFC Forum website](http://www.nfc-forum.org/).

Basically you would need to register a HCE service for the AID `D2760000850101` that implements a couple of APDU commands that the reader-side uses to access a Type 4 tag:

- SELECT NDEF tag application

  ```
  00 A4 04 00 07 D2760000850101 [00]
  ```
- SELECT capability container

  ```
  00 A4 00 0C 02 E103
  ```
- SELECT NDEF data file

  ```
  00 A4 00 0C 02 xxyy
  ```

  Where `xxyy` is the file ID of the NDEF data file as specified in the capability container.
- READ BINARY (for reading data from capability container or NDEF data file, whichever is currently selected)

  ```
  00 B0 xx yy zz
  ```

  Where `xx yy` is the offset to read at and `zz` is the number of bytes to read.

*Important note:* Be aware that such an NFC Forum Type 4 tag emulated by an Android device cannot be used to automatically trigger an app on a second Android device (at least not reliably?). Putting two Android devices together will usually result in them establishing a peer-to-peer link (even if Beam is turned off!). Only a foreground app on the second Android device could use the NFC Reader mode API to bypass Android Beam and reliably detect the emulated tag.

Comment: thanks for your response, but i cant follow you. do u know any example code?

Comment: No, I don't have any example code at hand (at least not when it comes to HCE). I suggest that you start your research by searching for "ISO 7816-4" and "APDU" and by reading the NFC Forum Type 4 Tag Operation specification.

Comment: Can you please explain why it cannot be used to "reliably" trigger an app or open url on a second device?

Comment: @electronix384128 The problem here is that R/W mode and P2P mode run simultaneously (sequentially polling different P2P and R/W technologies). Thus the other device could **either** be activated in card emulation mode (seeing the NDEF Tag Application) **or** be activated in P2P mode (seeing the SNEP service, etc). I assume this issue is also the reason why Google is abandoning P2P mode now.