# Android HCE with NDEF format and use iOS CoreNFC reader app to read it

Tags: android, nfc, hce, nfc-p2p, core-nfc

I have developed an android app with HCE function and want to send the string to iPhone by `CoreNFC`. So I have used [NFCReaderiOS](https://github.com/underwindfall/NFCReaderiOS), this example to verify whether success or not. The following code is the android part that I used to return data to the iOS `NFC reader` app:

```
@Override
public byte[] processCommandApdu(byte[] bytes, Bundle bundle) {
    if (Arrays.equals(bytes, APDU_SELECT)) {
        NdefMessage message = createTextMessage("Testing123");
        return message.toByteArray();
    } else {
        return A_ERROR;
    }
}
```

However, the iOS `NFC reader` app cannot capture any response that the android part returned. In this case, the function `processCommandApdu` is triggered by the iOS reader app. Is there any solution to emulate the `NDEF` tag by android `HCE` other than the above method? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you find anything which allows sending data to Android HCE from iOS? I'm kinda stuck at the same problem.

Comment: I'm sorry that I couldn't figure out how to send data to Android HCE from iOS. But I found that whenever I wrote data to Android HCE, the iOS writer would show "NFC tag is not writable"...I'm not sure whether this is the root cause

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that iOS supports anything other than the NDEF APDU.

Section 5 of http://apps4android.org/nfc-specifications/NFCForum-TS-Type-4-Tag_2.0.pdf
Should provide all the details how how to correctly emulate a type 4 tag with an NDEF message on it.

Also some more details on https://stackoverflow.com/a/29127714/2373819