# Emulate NDEF Tag in ReactNative for Android

Tags: android, react-native, nfc, ndef, hce

I am trying to emulate an NDEF message (NFC Forum Type 4 Tag) using ReactNative.
I could not find any working source code or module to achieve this. The only working application is from Maxsoft.bg named [NFC NDEF Tag Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maxsoft.ndeftagemulator) which is not open source.

So far I've used `react-native-nfc-manager` and `react-native-nfc-hce`, but I couldn't make it work.

I also checked the [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce) but I couldn't find a **working** example/sourcecode there as well.

I found it really strange that I couldn't find even one working source code! So, it would be great if you could help me with a **working ReactNative or Android** source code.

Comment: Hello any progress on this one? im trying to do exactly the same thing

Comment: The source code provided by @andrew worked just fine.
Unfortunately I did not have time to convert this into a React Native module.
It shouldn't be that hard! Good luck ;)

Comment: did react-native-nfc-hce didn't work for you?

Comment: No! I couldn't make it work. However, I don't know if I was doing something wrong or the package was not working. I also couldn't find any working code sample using react-native-nfc-hce.

Comment: @HBTB did you manage to make work with react native  ???

Comment: @FirasAbuFares Unfortunately not! We had a limited budget for this feature and the PO decided to go another way. As I said it shouldn't be hard to create a react native module out of a [working android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29122848/ndef-message-with-hce-android)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NDEF Message with HCE Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29122848/ndef-message-with-hce-android) should provide you with the answer for Native Java for Android, the best answer also has linked a github repo with source code demo.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Now I just have to turn it into a ReactNative module.

By any chance, do you know any existing module?

Comment: in case you're still looking, I learnt a fair bit about creating a react native module from the https://github.com/wix/react-native-newrelic repo.