# NFC Emulation on android using Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, nfc, hce

Been trying to create an NFC tag emulator for Android with flutter(Host Card Emulation)

But have been successful even after trying several different approaches .

Has any been able to get the NFC tag emulation on an android platform.?

The expectation is to use my mobile application for door access with emulated NFC tags instead of the standard RFID cards .

Tried a few times referring the flow from the links
https://pub.dev/documentation/nfc_emulator/latest/
https://www.zeromolecule.com/blog/host-card-emulation-hce-with-android-and-flutter/

Any guidance in the right direction or even better some sample code would be much appreciated .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Emulate NDEF Tag in ReactNative for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62876675/emulate-ndef-tag-in-reactnative-for-android)

Comment: So the HCE has to be in Native Java/Kotlin, so whether it's react native, flutter does not really matter to the core of the answer. The nfc_emulator package is just another basic wrapper but one that is coded to emulate a very limited type of NFC Tag for while you will have to write a specific reader app. Best to head right to the github project mentioned https://github.com/underwindfall/NFCAndroid. Also there is no one "Standard RFID" type of Tag, so NFC is unlikely to able to do door access card emulation unless the door access system is designed to work with it.